# Getting Site_ID in template Django

Tags: python, django

I have build a web site for a client which has a number of applications. Now he has a new URL registered which he wants to point to the same site, but he wants the look and feel changed. That's basically he wants a new home.html and base.html for the new web site. I can easily add the new site to settings and then change the view for the home page, to display a new home2.html.

However how do I do something like this as expressed in psuedo code in base.html

```
{% if site_id equals 1 %}

{% include "base1.html" %}

{% endif %}

{% if site_id equals 2 %}

{% include "base2.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

Any ideas. There are 100s of views on the site and nearly 50 models. I cannot recreate models, and mess around. This needs to be a quick fix.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can create a context processor to automatically add `site_id` to the context: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors

But I would opt for a different solution. You can simply add an extra template directory per site so Django will try the templates specifically for that site first and fall back to the normal templates if they're not available.

Comment: Isn't creating a context processor overkill?  Wouldn't adding it in the view be simpler?

Comment: @Andrew Slegde: if it was 1 view, yes. But he's saying that he's got "100s of views" which make something like that quite a tedious process ;)

Answer (score 1):

To extend the idea of WoLph with the context processor, I would maybe even add the switching of the template to the context processor which would clean up your templates, as otherwise you may have to repeat the if clause quite often:

```
from django.contrib.sites.models import Site

def base_template(request):
    site = Site.objects.get_current()
    template = "base%s.html" % str(site.pk)
    return {'BASE_TEMPLATE': template}
```

And in your template: `{% include BASE_TEMPLATE %}`

Looks nicer to me than the switching in the templates!

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be writing a Middleware to set ´request.site´ the current site id.